# MLMediaLibrary - Displaying the Photo Library -Swift Code Wrong - macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, icloud-photo-library

Trying to show photos from the Photo Library.  The Apple Sample Code below does not work properly.  It doesn't wait for the notifications but tries to launch the collection view which crashes at Number of Items in Section because there is no photo data to show.

Thanks for any help from you Swift guru's out there!

```
 /*
 Copyright (C) 2016 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 See LICENSE.txt for this sample’s licensing information

 Abstract:
 The `ViewController` class is a subclass to NSViewController responsible for managing the app's content.
 */

import Cocoa
import MediaLibrary

class IconViewBox : NSBox {
    override func hitTest(_ aPoint: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
        // Don't allow any mouse clicks for subviews in this NSBox.
        return nil
    }
}

// MARK: -

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - Types

    // Keys describing the dictionary for each photo loaded.
    private struct ItemKeys {
        static let imageKey = "icon"
        static let nameKey = "name"
    }

    // MLMediaLibrary property values for KVO.
    private struct MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys {
        static let mediaSourcesKey = "mediaSources"
        static let rootMediaGroupKey = "rootMediaGroup"
        static let mediaObjectsKey = "mediaObjects"
        static let contentTypeKey = "contentType"
    }

    // MARK: - Properties

    /**
     The KVO contexts for `MLMediaLibrary`.
     This provides a stable address to use as the `context` parameter for KVO observation methods.
     */
    private var mediaSourcesContext   = 1
    private var rootMediaGroupContext = 2
    private var mediaObjectsContext   = 3

    private var photoSize = CGSize(width: 168, height: 145)

    // Contains an array of dictionaries describing each photo (refer to ItemKeys for key/values).
    @IBOutlet weak var arrayController: NSArrayController!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var noPhotosLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet private weak var activityIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!

    // MLMediaLibrary instances for loading the photos.
    private var mediaLibrary: MLMediaLibrary!
    private var mediaSource: MLMediaSource!
    private var rootMediaGroup: MLMediaGroup!

    // MARK: - View Controller Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        print ("VDL1...................")
        // Start progress indicator in case fetching the photos from the photo library takes time.
        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimation(self)

        self.collectionView.minItemSize = self.photoSize
        self.collectionView.maxItemSize = self.photoSize

        self.arrayController.setSelectionIndex(-1)  // No selection to start out with.

        // Setup the media library to load only photos, don't include other source types.
        let options: [String : AnyObject] =
            [MLMediaLoadSourceTypesKey: MLMediaSourceType.image.rawValue as AnyObject,
             MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey: [MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier, MLMediaSourceiPhotoIdentifier] as AnyObject]

        // Create our media library instance to get our photo.
        mediaLibrary = MLMediaLibrary(options: options)

        // We want to be called when media sources come in that's available (via observeValueForKeyPath).
        self.mediaLibrary.addObserver(self,
                                      forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaSourcesKey,
                                      options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new,
                                      context: &mediaSourcesContext)

        if (self.mediaLibrary.mediaSources != nil) {

            print ("VDL2...................")
        } // Reference returns nil but starts the asynchronous loading.
    }

    deinit {

        // Make sure to remove us as an observer before "mediaLibrary" is released.
        self.mediaLibrary.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaSourcesKey, context:&mediaSourcesContext)
    }

    // MARK: - NSCollectionViewDataSource

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let photos = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects as! NSArray
        return photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "IconItem"), for:indexPath)
        let photos = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects as! NSArray
        let iconInfo = photos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]
        item.representedObject = iconInfo
        return item
    }

    // MARK: - NSCollectionViewDelegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {

        if let itemIndexPath = indexPaths.first {
            let photos = self.arrayController.arrangedObjects as! NSArray
            let itemDict = photos[((itemIndexPath as NSIndexPath).item)] as! NSDictionary
            if let itemTitle = itemDict[ItemKeys.nameKey] as? String {
                if (itemTitle.characters.count > 0) {
                    print("selected photo: '\(itemTitle)'")
                }
                else {
                    print("selected photo: <no title>")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Utilities

    /// Helps to make sure the media object is the photo format we want.
    private func isValidImage(_ mediaObject: MLMediaObject) -> Bool {

        var isValidImage = false

        let attrs = mediaObject.attributes
        let contentTypeStr = attrs[MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.contentTypeKey] as! String

        // We only want photos, not movies or older PICT formats (PICT image files are not supported in a sandboxed environment).
        if ((contentTypeStr != kUTTypePICT as String) && (contentTypeStr != kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie as String))
        {
            isValidImage = true
        }

        return isValidImage
    }

    /// Obtains the title of the MLMediaObject (either the meta name or the last component of the URL).
    func imageTitle(_ fromMediaObject: MLMediaObject) -> String {

        guard let title = fromMediaObject.attributes["name"] else {
            return fromMediaObject.url!.lastPathComponent
        }
        return title as! String
    }


    // MARK: - Photo Loading

    /// Observer for all key paths returned from the MLMediaLibrary.
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print ("Observe1...................")
        if (keyPath == MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaSourcesKey && context == &mediaSourcesContext && object! is MLMediaLibrary) {

            // The media sources have loaded, we can access the its root media.

            if let mediaSource = self.mediaLibrary.mediaSources?[MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier] {
                self.mediaSource = mediaSource
            }
            else if let mediaSource = self.mediaLibrary.mediaSources?[MLMediaSourceiPhotoIdentifier] {
                self.mediaSource = mediaSource
            }
            else {
                 print ("Observe2...................")
                // Can't find any media sources.
                self.noPhotosLabel.isHidden = false

                // Stop progress indicator.
                self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimation(self)

                return  // No photos found.
            }

            // Media Library is loaded now, we can access mediaSource for photos
            self.mediaSource.addObserver(self,
             forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.rootMediaGroupKey,
             options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new,
             context: &rootMediaGroupContext)

            // Obtain the media grouping (reference returns nil but starts asynchronous loading).
            if (self.mediaSource.rootMediaGroup != nil) {}
        }
        else if (keyPath == MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.rootMediaGroupKey && context == &rootMediaGroupContext && object! is MLMediaSource) {
             print ("Observe3...................")
            // The root media group is loaded, we can access the media objects.

            // Done observing for media groups.
            self.mediaSource.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.rootMediaGroupKey, context:&rootMediaGroupContext)

            self.rootMediaGroup = self.mediaSource.rootMediaGroup
            self.rootMediaGroup.addObserver(self,
                                            forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaObjectsKey,
                                            options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new,
                                            context: &mediaObjectsContext)

            // Obtain the all the photos, (reference returns nil but starts asynchronous loading).
            if (self.rootMediaGroup.mediaObjects != nil) {}
        }
        else if (keyPath == MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaObjectsKey && context == &mediaObjectsContext && object! is MLMediaGroup) {
             print ("Observe4...................")
            // The media objects are loaded, we can now finally access each photo.

            // Done observing for media objects that group.
            self.rootMediaGroup.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: MLMediaLibraryPropertyKeys.mediaObjectsKey, context:&mediaObjectsContext)

            // Stop progress indicator since we know if we have photos (or not).
            self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimation(self)

            let mediaObjects = self.rootMediaGroup.mediaObjects
            if (mediaObjects != nil && mediaObjects!.count > 0) {
                 print ("Observe5...................")
                // Add photos to the array, to be used in our NSCollectionView.
                for mediaObject in mediaObjects! {
                    if (self.isValidImage(mediaObject)) {    // Make sure the media object is a photo.

                        let title = self.imageTitle(mediaObject)

                        if let image = NSImage.init(contentsOf: mediaObject.thumbnailURL!) {
                            let iconItem : Dictionary = [ItemKeys.imageKey: image, ItemKeys.nameKey: title] as [String : Any]
                            self.arrayController.addObject(iconItem)
                        }
                    }
                }

                self.collectionView.reloadData()

            }
            else {
                // No photos available.
                self.noPhotosLabel.isHidden = false
            }

            self.rootMediaGroup = nil // We are done with this.
        }
        else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's ok if `numberOfItemsInSection` returns `0`. Please post a link to the Apple Sample Code. Did you make any changes?

Comment: Willeke, Thanks for taking a look at this.  The only changes I made were the print lines to try to understand what was going on, it doesn't get past the first print line.  With other swift code on macOS we have had similar issue with timing. Here is the link to the code.  Seems like even Apple can't keep up with all the swift versions.  This is swift 3 and no longer supported.  Thanks again for any help  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/MediaLibraryLoader/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017375

Comment: Shouldn't `ViewController` adopt `NSCollectionViewDataSource`? Try `class ViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource` and fix the errors.

Comment: Interesting..we usually set the dataSource delegate in the storyboard.  However, when setting it in the storyboard the compiler recognize the version errors in the code. Both of these methods were "enhanced" in swift 4 or 5:        'numberOfSectionsInCollectionView' has been renamed to 'numberOfSections(in:)'  'collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:)' has been renamed to 'collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)'  Making these corrections solves the problem.  However, there are still no photos being returned so there is an additional issue...Thanks!

Comment: It could be a privacy issue. Try adding `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` to info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

NSCollectionViewDataSource delegate is missing

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate, NSCollectionViewDataSource

Next you need to fix these methods: 'numberOfSectionsInCollectionView' has been renamed to 'numberOfSections(in:)' 'collectionView(:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:)' has been renamed to 'collectionView(:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)'